# The SQL statement works properly in SQL Server database, but errors in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, insert

I need to insert new record into a SQL Server database, but get

> Incorrect syntax error

The strange thing is when I try to query the same statement in SQL Server itself, it works properly.

The code in vb.net is as follows:

```
insertSql = "INSERT INTO Seg_LINE VALUES (" & OBJECTID & ", 'test" + "', '" + "test" + "','" + DrainName + "'," & UID & ")"
logger.Info("insert sql = " + insertSql)
Dim cmdInsert As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(insertSql, Sqlconnection) 
cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The `OBJECTID` and `UID` are number parameters.

I cannot figure out what's wrong with my code, I am using vb.net(vs2102).

Comment: This code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks... it's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: What is the SQL Statement output of the logger.Info?

Comment: Hi, the sql statement logged is : insert sql = INSERT INTO Seg_LINE VALUES (635,'test','test','Kallang',93571)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you have a DrainName value with a single quote in it. You're lucky the query is just failing, and not executing unwanted commands on your DB server. Don't use string concatenation like that to build queries! You need to use query parameters, like this:

```vb
insertSql = "INSERT INTO Seg_LINE VALUES (@ObjectID, 'test', 'test', @DrainName, @UID)"
logger.Info("insert sql = " + insertSql)
Dim cmdInsert As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(insertSql, Sqlconnection)
'I'm guessing at these parameter types. Use the actual db types of the columns
cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@ObjectID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = OBJECTID
cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@DrainName", SqlDbType.NChar, 50).Value = DrainName
cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@UID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = UID
cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Changing the code this way will also likely fix your syntax error.

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks a lot for the reply, but the result is the same. When I tried to create a new function and use the same code, it works properly.

Comment: Another thing to mention is although there has error, the data is store into the db table, but the program not proceed further.

Comment: Hi Joel, when I change ExecuteNonQuery to ExecuteScalar, it works properly, thanks for the attention.